# Not able to convert numeric to String in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, numeric, postgresql-9.2

I am not able to convert numeric to string. For example below is the query:

```
select to_char(50000.00,'999D99S')
```

Any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Below syntax helped me:

```
select 50000.00::text as content
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add more `9`:

```
select to_char(50000.00,'99 999D99S');
```

If you don't know how much decimal you can have, just do something like:

```
select to_char(50000.00,'999 999 999 999D99S');
```